# How do I get rid of the deprecation warnings on my aws_route_table definitions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

All of my route table definitions throw a deprecation warning during the plan/apply stages. I can't figure out how I should be defining my routes so that I stop getting these warnings.

Here's an example of one of my route table resources:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "rtb_public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.app_vpc.id
  route = [
    {
      cidr_block                 = "0.0.0.0/0"
      gateway_id                 = aws_internet_gateway.app_igw.id
      egress_only_gateway_id     = ""
      instance_id                = ""
      ipv6_cidr_block            = null
      nat_gateway_id             = ""
      network_interface_id       = ""
      transit_gateway_id         = ""
      vpc_peering_connection_id  = ""
      carrier_gateway_id         = ""
      core_network_arn           = ""
      destination_prefix_list_id = ""
      local_gateway_id           = ""
      vpc_endpoint_id            = ""
    }
  ]
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.vpc_name}-rtb-public"
  }
}
```

This results in the following output from Terraform:

```
Warning: Argument is deprecated
...
Use network_interface_id instead
```

[The docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route_table) mention that `instance_id` is deprecated. However, if I try to remove it from my routes, I get an error telling me instance_id is required.

In case it matters, here are the versions from my state file:

```
"version": 4,
"terraform_version": "1.3.9",
"serial": 83,
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that all those attributes are only required on the route objects when the aws_route_table.route parameter is an array. Changing the route parameter to a single object allowed me to remove all of the unused object properties, like this:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "rtb_public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.app_vpc.id
  route {
    cidr_block      = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id      = aws_internet_gateway.app_igw.id
    ipv6_cidr_block = null
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.vpc_name}-rtb-public"
  }
}
```

This didn't work for me the first time because I'd mistakenly put an `=` after route.

Comment: It seems like this argument is using the special legacy [Attributes as Blocks mode](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/attr-as-blocks) for compatibility with quirks of older versions of Terraform. If the provider documentation for `route` didn't mention that then that's a documentation bug -- any argument using this legacy mode should be documented as such -- and so probably worth reporting in [the AWS provider repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws).